# Accessors and Mutators

Tags: c++, private-members, pure-virtual

I am barely learning about Pure virtual functions. I have a pure virtual function `virtual int createCharacter() = 0;` and I am adding characterStrength, characterDexterity and characterIntelligence which are private members in my class. I know I need to add accessors and mutators but I don't know how. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am trying to display the total back in main, but I am getting these errors :

```
Human.h: In function âint main()â:
Human.h:12: error: âint Human::characterStrengthâ is private
maingame.cpp:48: error: within this context
Human.h:13: error: âint Human::characterDexterityâ is private
maingame.cpp:48: error: within this context
Human.h:12: error: âint Human::characterStrengthâ is private
maingame.cpp:48: error: within this context
Human.h:14: error: âint Human::characterIntelligenceâ is private
maingame.cpp:48: error: within this context
Human.h:15: error: âstd::string Human::characterTypeâ is private
maingame.cpp:50: error: within this context
Human.h:16: error: âint Human::characterTotalâ is private
maingame.cpp:50: error: within this context
```

This is my code :

```
#include "Human.h"
#include "Orc.h"


using namespace std;

//Main.cpp
int main()
{
    //Character cc;
    Human H;
    Orc O;
    char choice;
    char userC;
    cout << "Welcome!\n";
    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "Pick your choice:\n";
    cout << "A -- Human\n";
    cout << "B -- Orc\n";
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice)
    {

        case 'a':
        case 'A':
                    H.getType();
                    H.getStrength();
                    H.getDexterity();
                    H.getIntelligence();
                    H.createCharacter();

                    if (H.characterStrength > H.characterDexterity && H.characterStrength > H.characterIntelligence)
                    {
                        cout << "The strong " << H.characterType << " has a total score of " << H.characterTotal << endl;
                    }

    }



    return 0;
}
```

---

```
//human.h
#ifndef HUMAN_H
#define HUMAN_H

#include "Character.h"

using namespace std;

class Human : public Character 
{
    private:
                int characterStrength;
                int characterDexterity;
                int characterIntelligence;
                string characterType;
                int characterTotal;

    public:
                Human();//Constructor 
                                ~Human();

                int getStrength ()
                {
                    cout << "Strength : Enter a number from 0 to 18\n";
                    cin >> characterStrength;

                    return characterStrength;
                }

                int getDexterity ()
                {
                    cout << "Dexterity : Enter a number from 0 to 18\n";
                    cin >> characterDexterity;

                    return characterDexterity;
                }

                int getIntelligence ()
                {
                    cout << "Intelligence : Enter a number from 0 to 18\n";
                    cin >> characterIntelligence;

                    return characterIntelligence;
                }

                string getType ()
                {
                    cout << "Please choose one of the following\n";
                    cout << "A -- Paladin \n";
                    cout << "B -- Ranger \n";
                    cout << "C -- Wizard \n";\
                    cin >> characterType;

                    return characterType;
                }

                virtual int createCharacter()
                {
                    characterTotal = characterStrength + characterIntelligence + characterDexterity;
                    return characterTotal;
                }


};

#endif
```

---

```
//Character.h
#ifndef CHARACTER_H
#define CHARACTER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Character
{
    protected:
                float characterTotal;

    public:

                virtual int createCharacter() = 0; //Pure virtual function
                Character();
                ~Character();

};

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Well. The compiler message is pretty straightforward. You are trying to access private members outside a class, which is prohibited. Lets try some simple example to get a hand on things:

```
class Character
{
public:
  virtual std::string GetClass() = 0;
  int GetHP() {return(m_nHP);};
  int GetMP() {return(m_nMP);};
  //You must declare virtual destructor!
  virtual ~Character() {};
protected:
  int m_nHP, m_nMP;
};

class Warrior : public Character
{
public:
  Warrior() : m_nHP(100), m_nMP(0)
  std::string GetClass(){  return("Warrior"); };
};

class Mage : public Character
{
public:
  Mage() : m_nHP(30), m_nMP(100)
  std::string GetClass(){  return("Mage"); };
};

int main(void)
{
  Character* pChar = new Mage();
  std::cout << pChar->GetClass()<<pChar->GetHP()<<pChar->GetMP();
  delete pChar;
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: Putting parens after `return` is silly. It's a keyword, not a function call.